# Fixing address errors using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, address, string

I am working on a task that will calculate a field to fix errors stemming from the Standardize Addresses tool and human error with the input data.

The script is below. I'm getting Error 000989 "Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Line 6)"

Note: ADDR_SN and ADDR_SD seems to be a truncated output of Street Name and Street Direction (There is some confusion as the Standardize Address tool is new to me)

Any pointers to help fix this code?

Expression:

```
AddSN2( !ADDR_SN!, !ADDR_SD!)
```

ADDR_SN is the Street Name and ADDR_SD is the street direction.

Code Block:

```
def AddSN2(StNa, STDir):
    if (StNa == "BEND"):
        return (STDir+ +StNa)
    elif (StNa == "CEDAR GARDEN"):
        return (StNa.replace(" ", "")
    else:
        return StNa
```

[image: Script]
[image: Table]

Comment: I dunno if this is your issue, but here:

return (STDir+ +StNa)

should be 

return (STDir+ ' ' +StNa)

Comment: This is a helpful tip, but it didn't clear the syntax error.

Comment: Is the field length of AddSN2 long enough?

Comment: The field length is 100, which should accommodate all street names.

Comment: The row indentation is wrong for the first return statement

Comment: Ooooh, good eye BERA!

Comment: The additional space is an error in my copy/pasted script into the question prompt. There are equal indentations throughout the script; four spaces for the if/elif/else statements and 8 spaces for all return. I'll fix this error in the question to resolve further issues.

Comment: @BERA although it might look/seem wrong, python will still accept it as there are no other lines in *that* block with a different indentation

Answer (score 7):

You have a lot of unnecessary and one unclosed parentheses. The unclosed one in line 5 is causing the syntax error to be thrown in line 6. To correct and clean up, try this:

```
def AddSN2(StNa, STDir):
    if StNa == "BEND":
        return STDir+" "+StNa
    elif StNa == "CEDAR GARDEN":
        return StNa.replace(" ", "")
    else:
        return StNa
```

Comment: +1 @Jbarne also note that this fixes the `+ +` in line 3 as well (which would have raised an error once the missing parentheses is added into line 5)

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer certainly addresses your syntax errors. But just from a "code review" perspective that I always found useful when I was learning how to program, here's a more advanced way to write this kind of code that is a bit more generic and therefore easier to extend:

```py
replacements = {
  "BEND": lambda name, dir: " ".join([name, dir)],
  "CEDAR GARDEN": lambda name, dir: name.replace(" ", "")
}

default = lambda name, dir: name

def format_addresses(name, dir):
    if name in replacements:
        formatting_function = replacements[name]
    else:
        formatting_function = default
    return formatting_function(name, dir)
```

Then, as you go on, it's a bit easier to extend replacements with more formatters: just add a new key/value, with each value being a [lambda function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function) that takes the name and direction values). Actually, they don't need to be lambda functions, if you need a bit more logic in a formatter then they can be references to a named function. The point is that it means you only need to adjust the `replacements` variable, and not the `format_addresses` function itself.

Another way to write that `format_addresses` function is:

```py
def format_addresses(name, dir):
    return replacements.get(name, default)(name, dir)
```

This is even more advanced again, and probably a bit too confusing to be worth it. However I've included it because if you do get your head around it, you'll understand a bit more Python, which can only help you in the future.